# Adding TextView dynamically to an layout for a messaging app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am trying to build a simple messaging app. which have one EditText and one Button at the bottom of the screen. when someone enters text and click the send button the entered text should appear as a msg on the top of the (EditText and Button). If the user have sent lots of msgs unable to fit to fit in the screen, the scrollbar for scrolling and viewing msgs should automatically appear.

I have made the layout as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Java code to fetch the msg is

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
}
```

I need someone to guide me how to proceed after this.

I want the msg to appear above each time. Any help or suggestion will be great helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, you might want to try using one textview. You just keep adding the new messages to it.
I would create my own custom layout just so that different combinations are possible (e.g timestamps, emojis). Basically a custom layout which draws all your different items on there.

Comment: can we add a one textview each time the button is pressed? what will be the parent container for this text view. so that it can scroll when there are more textview

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. Create a scrollview with viewgroup inside and use addview to add new textview in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `listView` with 9patch images.